# How do you find the peak-to-peak ripple voltage of a full wave bridge rectifier?

Tags: rectifier, ripple, full-bridge

[image: Circuit]

The 32VRMS secondary of a transformer feeds a full wave rectifier and capacitor filter as shown in
the circuit.

The peak-to-peak ripple of the output voltage of this circuit needs to be less than 1V when it delivers
a current of 3A. A filter capacitor of about 30 000 uF is required. I need to find the frequency.

I am unsure of the formula for finding peak-to-peak ripple voltage of a full wave bridge rectifier.

Is this correct:

```
V(p-p) = I/(2*f*C)
```

Therefore, f = 50 Hz.

I am unsure because I have seen the equation:

```
V(p-p) = Vm/(2*f* R*C)
```

used.

Which equation is correct?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it? Is this homework?

Comment: It's not homework, i am just confused which formula to use

Comment: If you work at understanding the circuit from first principles you'll never have to remember the formulas or how to apply them.

Comment: But i don't understand the circuit from first principles

Comment: What's your end goal? A numeric answer to this question or a deeper understanding?

Comment: Both to be honest, obviously a deeper understanding is way more important but I do want to also know numerically how it works

Comment: The first equation doesn't have any term denoting the load or the current drawn. A load which draws more current will definitely cause a bigger dip in the capacitor voltage. So first equation is probably wrong. In the second equation, there is an R in the denominator. A smaller R draws more current and hence more dip in the capacitor voltage. Hence the second equation is more likely correct. Derivations are usually given in most textbooks.

Comment: Yes sorry i by mistake left I out. It is suppose to be V(p-p) = I/(2fC)

Comment: Please edit your question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

Vm/(2.f.R.C)=I/(2.f.C) as Vm/R =I where Vm is the max voltage